# protobuf-javalite + kotlin A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers

so, i had a working android project using
`implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1'`
but then i added facebook login. that cause duplicate class exception

```
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.12.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.12.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
```

so i changed the above line to
`implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.12.0'`

and added

```
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            //...
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option "lite"
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
```

and now when i try to build the project im getting
`A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution`

Is there anyway to solve this?